# How can I select a cell without touching the screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and want to move down a cell in my table every time the accelerometer's X axis is greater then 0.5 (when this event occurs i increment a value named "TEST" ). How can i change the background of a cell that has it's indexPath.row equal to TEST ?

Here is how i try to access the method(from the accelerometer function) but it gives me an error :

```
  - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration 
{


              if(acceleration.x>0.5)
                TEST++; 
            if(TEST<0) TEST=0;
            if(TEST>19) TEST=19;

             NSIndexPath *temp = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:TEST];
            [self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:temp];


    }

     I have 20 rows in my table (hence the clamp).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:

Selects a row in the receiver identified by index path, optionally scrolling the row to a location in the receiver.

- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition

Parameters

indexPath

An index path identifying a row in the receiver.

animated
YES if you want to animate the selection and any change in position, NO if the change should be immediate.

scrollPosition

A constant that identifies a relative position in the receiving table view (top, middle, bottom) for the row when scrolling concludes. See “Table View Scroll Position”

here

```
            NSIndexPath *temp = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:TEST];


       [self.tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:temp animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Comment: i get a "thread 1. Program received signal : "SIGABRT" " at "[self.tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:temp animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];"

Comment: u should type as it is .dont copy

Comment: or use [self tableView] instead of self.tableview.

Comment: there seems to be a problem at my NSIndexPath initialization : "Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row."; what am i doing wrong ? i can't see it .

Comment: NSIndexPath *temp = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:0];

Answer (score 1):

How about `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`?

Comment: It would be interesting to see accelerometer input combined with this. Nice!

Comment: i get a "thread 1. Program received signal : "SIGABRT" " when i call this function :  [[self tableView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath : temp atScrollPosition : UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated : YES];